# Python - Run a simple command-line program with prompted I/O and "proxy" it, on Windows

Tags: python, windows, console, subprocess, interactive

I have a simple command-line binary program `hello` which outputs to STDOUT:

```
What is your name?
```

and waits for the user to input it. After receiving their input it outputs:

```
Hello, [name]!
```

and terminates.

I want to use Python to run computations on the final output of this program (`"Hello, [name]!"`), however before the final output I want the Python script to essentially "be" the binary program. In other words I'd like Python to forward all of the prompts to STDOUT and then accept the user's input and give it to the program. However I want to hide the final output so I can process it and show my own results to the user. I do not want to replicate the `hello`'s behavior in the script, as this simple program is a stand-in for a more complex program that I am actually working with.

I was hoping there would be some sort of mechanic in `subprocess` where I would be able to do something akin to:

```
while process.is_running():
    next_char = process.stdout.read(1)
    if next_char == input_prompt_thing: # somehow check if the program is waiting for input
        user_input = raw_input(buffer)
        process.stdin.write(user_input)
    else:
        buffer += next_char
```

I have been playing with `subprocess` and essentially got as far as realizing I could use `process.stdout.read(1)` to read from the program before it began blocking, but I can't figure out how to break this loop before the process blocks my Python script. I am not too familiar with console I/O and it is not an area of much expertise for me, so I am starting to feel pretty lost. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`winpexpect`](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home) (not tested):

```
import re
from winpexpect import winspawn

p = winspawn('hello')
prompt = "What is your name?"
p.expect(re.escape(prompt))
name = raw_input(prompt)
p.sendline(name)
p.expect("Hello, .*!")
output = p.after
# ...
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this without encoding some of the shell program's logic in the Python script? Since this library comes from TCL, is it an inherent problem when attempting to interact with shell scripts in general?

Comment: @leo-the-manic: You don't need to replicate the whole logic, just the place where the shell program expects input: `p.expect()` will skip an unrelated output; you could retrieve it with `p.before` afterward.